# env.BUILD_ID Build number - Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have Jenkins master with two slaves(jenkins agent).

`env.BUILD_ID` gives build number

Reason for this question is, if two Jenkins slave build the same branch code, am wondering the `BUILD_ID` value to be same.

---

Does Jenkins master create unique build number for any job running on any slave?

or

Is build number unique within slave?

What is the scope of `env.BUILD_ID` number uniqueness? across slaves...

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Master creates the BUILD_ID or the BUILD_NUMBER. It is specific to the job and does not depend on the number of slaves it is running on.

Comment: So... Each job has its sequence of build numbers. But, master generates it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the master creates it. You will not have 2 different build numbers for 2 different slaves.

Comment: What do you mean two different build numbers? Every job running on any slave will have its own sequence starting from number 1. Isn't it? That is exactly the `env.BUILD_ID` per job.

Comment: Build Number is same as Build Id. For instance, you have a pipeline that has two stages. Stage 1 builds on slave A and stage 2 builds on slave B. Now, when you trigger the job for the first time, you will get BUILD_ID = 1 and it will execute both stages (1 & 2) on Slave A & B. When you execute the job again, you will get BUILD_ID = 2 and both the stages will be executed again.

Comment: In your question, you mentioned two slaves build the same branch code. I think you are starting the job twice. The first time you start the Jenkins job, your code builds on Slave A and the second time you build the code, your code builds on Slave B. If that is the case, then you will have two distinct BUILD_ID.

Comment: Consider a scenario, we have two different jobs in same slave, pulling/building the same code from same source and branch... Still Build id will be specific to job starting from sequence number 1... Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196488/discussion-between-bilcy-and-overexchange).